# Getting the input strings into an array in C

Tags: c

In C, we do something like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

printf("The first argument is %s", argv[1]);
printf("The second argument is %s", argv[2]);
return 0;

}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to store strings in an array in similar way as above when using scanf or fgets .

I tried like:

```
char **input;
scanf("%s", &input);
```

Anyway I can access the strings entered as input[0], input[1].. so on...

Comment: Wanted to ask this since two days. :P Finally, someone else did. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you need to make sure you have enough space to do so:

```
char input[3][50]; // enough space for 3 strings with
                   // a length of 50 (including \0)

fgets(&input[0], 50, stdin);
```

```
printf("Inputted string: %s\n", input[0]);
```

Using `char **input` does not have any space allocated for the input, therefore you cannot do it.

Comment: let's say we have three words entered as input separated by space. I want to store these three words in the array. there can be any number of words.. I want to access these words like we access the arguments passed to main(). I believe in your example above everything entered is stored in the input[0]

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but somewhat tedious, especially if you don't know the number of strings at the beginning.

```
char **input;
```

That much is fine. From there, you need allocate an array of (the right number of) pointers:

```
input = malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_LINES);
```

Then you need to allocate space for each line. Since you typically only want enough space for each string, you typically do something like this:

```
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 8192

static char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
long current_line = 0;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), infile) && current_line < MAX_LINES)  {
    input[current_line] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
    strcpy(buffer[current_line++], buffer);
}
```

If you don't know the number of lines up-front, you typically allocate a number of pointers to start with (about as above), but as you read each line, check whether you've exceeded the current allocation, and if you have realloc the array of pointers to get more space.

If you want to badly enough, you can do the same with each individual line. Above, I've simply set a maximum that's large enough you probably won't exceed it very often with most typical text files. If you need it larger, it's pretty easy to expand that. At the same time, any number you pick will be an arbitrary limit. If you want to, you can read a chunk into your buffer, and if the last character in the string is not a new-line, keep reading more into the same string (and, again, use realloc to expand the allocation as needed). This isn't terribly difficult to do, but covering all the corner cases correctly can/does get tedious.

Edit: I should add that there's a rather different way to get the same basic effect. Read the entire content of the file into a single big buffer, then (typically) use strtok to break the buffer into lines (replacing "\n" with "\0") to build an array of pointers into the buffer. This typically improves speed somewhat (one big read instead of many one-line reads) as well as allocation overhead  because you use one big allocation instead of many small ones. Each allocation will typically have a header, and get rounded to something like a (multiple of some) power of two. The effect of this varies with the line length involved. If you have a few long lines, it probably won't matter much. If you have a lot of short lines, it can save a *lot*.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I am actually trying to develop something like bash that can run program, scripts and manage variables. The user enters commands followed by arguments. I am trying to access all the strings entered through an array. In your example above, i believe you are assuming the string to be much bigger like a text file.. It seems like for my case, I need to first read the strings in buffer then using space as separator. separate the strings and store in array by dynamically defining it. Could there be any other alternative??

Comment: Shouldn't `currentline < MAX_LINES-1` just be `currentline < MAX_LINES`?

Comment: @suenda: Yes, I interpreted your mention of scanf and fgets as indicating that you were planning to read input from a file. If you're interested in command line arguments, then you can just read through `argv[1]`...`argv[argc-1]`.

Comment: @Dmitri: Yeah, sounds right. I get so used to subtracting 1 when dealing with string lengths in C, that when I'm dealing with strings I start to do the same where I shouldn't...